# Why will ajax call keep on functioning even if php handler is edited?

Tags: php, ajax

Okay, this makes me completely baffled...
There is an Ajax call to a php function that has a mysql query and json_encode at the end. I'm just debugging something using Chrome console.. Anyway. I just tried to delete both query and json_encode from that php and save the php. Guess what Ajax kept on working. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser probably cached the response from a previous AJAX call. Try clearing your cache and it should fail.